# Opening .mea file in R

Tags: r, file

I have downloaded a file with the extension `.mea`. It's climate data. I don't know how to import it in r. even I don't know how to open in MacOS. Here is what the first lines of data look like.

```
IPCC Data Distribution Centre Results from model  HADCM3     11-07-2002
Grid is  96 *  73   Month is Jan
HADCM   A1F
Total precipitation  (mm/day)                                                   
  7008   format is (10F8.2)   missing code is  9999.99                          
    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: You need to give us more information here.  When you open the `mea` file in a text editor, what do you see?  Do you see readable data, or just a bunch of binary-esque garbage?  Is this a binary file, or a regular flat file?

Comment: I could open it with CotEditor. Its readable data. when I get more info of the file, the kind is shown as Document. But the extension is .mea.

Comment: Have you tried `readLines()` yet?  Sometimes extensions don't matter in R.

Comment: Edit your question and include the first 2-3 lines from this file.  @RichScriven using `readLines` may not even be necessary; we won't know until we see the actual data.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean, trying *something* might be useful.  Sounds like OP might have given up before he even started because of the file extension.

Comment: What I see after opening with editor is not what its supposed to be based on the data description. This is my problem.

Comment: I believe the file format [is described here](http://www.ipcc-data.org/sres/gcm_fileformat.html).

Comment: There is explanation on how to read IPCC files in R here: http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/reading-into-R-IPCC-data-files-td5925687.html.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the following way:

First I split the file into 12 small files, each containing one month's data, using the command line "split" function:

```
split -l 706 filename newfilePrefix
```

Then read in each small file with the following

```
readr::read_table(filename, col_names=FALSE, skip=5)
```